# Why does this drop-cookie javascript not work in Firefox 38?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

I got the script from here: http://www.creare.co.uk/js-eu-cookie-law-banner

It was originally designed to create a cookie-consent banner on websites. It creates a cookie on page load. If you close the banner, the banner does not appear again (or until whatever expiry time you give the cookie).

I don't want to use it for cookie-consent, but instead to create a welcome banner which won't appear again on return visits. Here's a test-page: http://www.gattapelata.it/cookie-test.html

It works as desired in Chrome and IE-11 (Windows), and in Safari, Opera and Chrome (iPad, iOS 8 ). But... not in Firefox 38 (Windows). No cookie is dropped and on page re-load the banner re-appears.

**PS:** The Firefox I'm using collects cookies from other sites.

Comment: The problem is your firefox settings - firefox works as advertised

Comment: Ah yes, I had "Accept cookies from sites" unchecked (which must mean all those other site cookies I found under "Page info" were deposited on my computer before I unchecked it). With that  checked, it works. But, of course, it won't work for anyone with "Accept cookies from sites" unchecked.

Comment: that's a users prerogative